# Instantaneous data transfer to custom cell from viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to activate a function inside my custom cell by setting the value of a boolean inside the custom cell class. This is my best attempt at doing this:

```
func blurViewActive(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began) {
        println("STATE BEGAN")

        var point = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.tv)
        if let indexPath = self.tv.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point) {

            let data = messageList[indexPath.row] as Messages
            let mcell: TableViewCell = self.tv.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as TableViewCell
            mcell.read = true
        }
    }
}
```

but this doesn't work, and I really have no idea how to do this any other way.

Here is the code for my custom cell class:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelOutl: UILabel!

    var timer = NSTimer()
    var counter = 10

    var read = Bool()

    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        if read == true{
        println("hello")
        }
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)


    }
    func timerStarted(){
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    func update(){
    println(--counter)
    }
}
```

My expected outcome is that once read has been set to "true" in my view controller, the function inside awakeFromNib-function should be executed instantaneously.

Comment: What doesn't work about this? What is your expected outcome? Have you tried calling the function directly?

Comment: @IanMacDonald My expected outcome is that once read has been set to "true" in my view controller, the function inside awakeFromNib-function should be executed instantaneously. See more information above.

Comment: You should override `TableViewCell` `func setRead` to accomplish this. Your `awakeFromNib` will not be called when you update a property value.

Comment: @IanMacDonald If you could please provide the code for that solution that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a number of points of confusion here.

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns a cell for use in the table view it is called on. This will be either a newly instantiated cell or an existing cell not currently displayed in any of the table's visible rows. Setting the `read` property on this cell will therefore have no immediate visible effect.

If you want access to a visible cell you could use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but even then changes made to that cell will not necessarily update the UI. Instead you probably want to update whatever model backs that cell and call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` to update a specific cell.

Additionally `awakeFromNib` will be called only when a new cell is created. That will be before  it is returned from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` and therefore well before you can take any action on it, like setting its `read` property. It will also not be called once per row in your table or per displayed row since you are using a reuse identifier. Instead the table view will create at least one cell for each visible row and reuse them as row scroll into and out of sight. This is convenient because minimizing the number of objects created helps reduce memory use and reduces load which could slow down scrolling performance. However it means that your data source needs to be prepared to update these cells as they are reused from one row to the next.